# Symfony2 Form avoid writing password on each submit

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I've just created a symfony2 form where I have a repeated password type. The whole form has a unique save submit button so right now the user is forced to write the password on each submit.

How do I avoid entering the password each time?

Comment: Is the password required? If not you could just ignore the field when it's empty. To see how to do it, have a look at FOSUserBundle. The User-Model has a property plainPassword which is not persisted but used in `UserManager::updatePassword(UserInterface $user)` to change the encoded password if plainPassword is not empty.

Comment: Right now i'm ignoring the password when it's null as it's not required on the form, gonna take a look at FosUserBundle. Thanks a lot!